# Redirect routing in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-routing

I'm trying to set up a CakePHP redirect route, but I'm stuck. Reading the book didn't help so far.

I want to redirect the URL `/mysite/xyz` to `/mysite/en/xyz` (which includes a language parameter)

The route for the final URL, `/mysite/en/xyz`, is set up like so, and works fine:

```
Router::connect(
    '/:language/:category/*',  
    array('controller' => 'content', 'action' => 'index'),  
    array(
        'named' => array('language', 'category'),
        'language' => 'en|de',
        'category' => 'abc|def|xyz', 
        'pass' => array('language', 'category')
    )
);
```

The redirect route is set up like so:

```
Router::redirect(
    '/:category/*',  
    array('controller' => 'content', 'action' => 'index', 'language' => 'en'),
    array(
        'named' => array('category'),
        'category' => 'abc|def|xyz', 
        'pass' => array('language'),
        'persist' => array('category')
    )
);
```

However, if I now access the URL `/mysite/xyz`, I'm redirected to `/mysite/mysite/en/xyz/en` - note the duplication of parameters.

How can I set this up correctly?

Comment: Have you tried to remove `'pass' => array('language', 'category')` in your Router::connect ?

Comment: @Oliboy50: 'pass' => array('language', 'category') is in the first route, which works fine as it is. It's the redirect route I'm having problems with.